# form action calls php on the same file

Tags: php, forms

ry to call the php code that's in the same file as the form.
but this has problem.. please help!

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" >
<select name = "filter">

</select>
</form>

<?php
   if isset(["filter"]){
  $db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=project", "root","");
            $c_type = ["filter"];
            $rows = $db->query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE type="$c_type");
   }
   else{
     $db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=project", "root","");
            $rows = $db->query("SELECT * FROM table);
}
```

Comment: You have more than likely truncated your own issue, please return the entire code and leaving out anything concerning to privacy

Comment: We get the same "error" looking at your question

Comment: what do you mean by `isset(["filter"]`?

Comment: See @Florian's response, or provide more code.

Comment: i just edit the code that's what i have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will fix it:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST["filter"])) {
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=project", "root","");
    $c_type = $_POST["filter"];
    $rows = $db->query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE type='{$c_type}'");
}
else
{
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=project", "root","");
    $rows = $db->query("SELECT * FROM table");
}
?>
```

Comment: Which `$array` is that? according to the problem description, it has to be `$_POST`

Answer (score 1):

Try This :

```
<form action="#" method="POST">
<select name = "filter">

</select>
</form>

<?php
   if (isset($_POST['filter'])){
       echo "ok";
   }
   else{
      echo "not set";
}
?>
```

Comment: Parenthesis on echo?

Comment: @Zanderwar, why not?

Comment: @sectus Why? :P I get RSI enough without typing more than needed lol

Comment: Yes, parenthesis on echo is optional.

Comment: @Zanderwar, so, that is the answer: Florian has no RSI % )